# How to return object along with HttpResponseMessage.ReasonPhrase

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

In the following method:

```
        public async Task<T> GetAsync(TResourceIdentifier identifier)
        {
            var responseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_addressSuffix + identifier);

            if(responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();

            return null;
        }
```

I am returning null if the response is not successful or else I will return the T however it is defined.

In synch methods, I would pass a string paramater by ref `(ref string errMsg)` that would carry the http response but I am not sure how to do it with Async calls? What I would like to do is to return an error message along with the object (null or not) to display on my winform message if it is not successful. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

> I am returning null if the response is successful

That doesn't really make sense.  A method with a `Get` tells me something should be returned.

> What I would like to do is to return an error message along with the object (null or not) to display on my winform message if it is not successful.

You can wrap your response in an object and use [the *new* pattern matching with the `is` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is) to make code look really readable:

```
public interface ICallResult { }

public class CallSuccessful : ICallResult { }

public class CallFail : ICallResult 
{
   public string Details { get; set; }
}

public async Task<ICallResult> GetAsync(TResourceIdentifier identifier)
```

usage:

```
if ((await o.GetAsync(identifier)) is CallFail callFail)
{
  Console.WriteLine(callFail.Details);
}

// or
if ((await o.GetAsync(identifier)) is CallSuccessful)
{
}
```

Some purest's may dislike the usage of an empty class, but I would argue the readability, maintainability and extensibility out weight empty classes, but it really depends on your context.

Comment: What do you return, if not null, when the item you are requesting does not exist in the database?